# Elixir/Phoenix binary_to_atom

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a form

`<%= select f, :user_id, ["刺繡等等我": "2", "wow": "3"] %>`

If I use only english language, it works perfectly. But chinese, or any other returns error

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
:erlang.binary_to_atom("刺繡等等我", :utf8)
(elixir) src/elixir_parser.yrl:512: :elixir_parser.yeccpars2_93/7
```

I believe it has do to with the encoding. How can I convert the string to the acceptable format?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atoms cannot contain codepoints above 255 as of the current version of Erlang (19).

> binary_to_atom(Binary, utf8)
>
> fails if the binary contains Unicode codepoints > 255. In a future release, such Unicode characters can be allowed and binary_to_atom(Binary, utf8) does then not fail.

[Source](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_atom-2)

The `["刺繡等等我": "2"]` syntax is equivalent to `[{:erlang.binary_to_atom("刺繡等等我"), "2"}]` i.e. it converts all the keys to atoms and the text you're using contains codepoints over 255.

Since `select` supports any enumerable that yields 2 item tuples, you can construct the list of two element tuples of strings using the longer notation:

```
 <%= select f, :user_id, [{"刺繡等等我", "2"}, {"wow", "3"}] %>
```

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert for the answer! I will take a look now at the source.