# Recursively convert Map to Keyword List

Tags: dictionary, recursion, elixir

I found a function to turn maps into keyword lists on the internet, but it is not recursive:

```
def to_keyword_list(dict) do
    Enum.map(dict, fn({key, value}) -> {String.to_atom(key), value} end)
end
```

I then made this one, but it gives me an error.

```
def tokey(dict) do
  Enum.map(dict, fn({key, value}) ->
    if is_map value do
      {String.to_atom(key), tokey(value)}
    else
      {String.to_atom(key), value}
    end
  end)
end
```

Result of the first one:

```
["calig├╝eva": %{speeking: "speeeeeeee"}, test: "teet", tututu: "tururuuu"]
```

Result of the second one:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_atom(:speeking, :utf8)
    code.exs:10: anonymous fn/1 in Util.tokey/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1233: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1772: Enum.map/2
    code.exs:8: anonymous fn/1 in Util.tokey/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1233: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
```

Is there an easier or more effective way of doing this? And why does it show that error? Can I not call a function from within itself?

Result of first one changing `ü` for `u`:

```
[caligueva: %{speeking: "speeeeeeee"}, test: "teet", tututu: "tururuuu"]
```

Second one outputs the same error. This is the map I'm using:

```
map = %{
  "test" => "teet",
  "tututu" => "tururuuu",
  "caligueva" => %{"speeking": "speeeeeeee"}
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating atoms here? Atoms cannot contain characters with codepoint > 255 while you have a `├╝` in there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351625/elixir-phoenix-binary-to-atom/41351787#41351787

Comment: I'm going to be using a module that requires keyword lists as form (HTTPoison), so I'm going to be using Poison.decode json-to-map to receive, and this function to encode the output. Also, I tried without the special character and it gives out the exact same error.

Comment: Ah right, I misread the error. The error is because you called `String.to_atom` on something that already was an atom (`:speeking`). (You would have hit the special character error later.)

Comment: Does HTTPoison even support nested keyword lists as form? Doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. I guess I'll be changing strategy. Also, I added the map that I am using, where "speeeking" is a string, not an atom. I guess I'll be using a json if I need clusters.

Comment: You need to use `=>` instead of `:` if you want a string there. `%{"speeking": "speeeeeeee"} == %{speeking: "speeeeeeee"}`.

Comment: Damn, I feel dumb now. Too much Javascript. Result: `[caligueva: [speeking: "speeeeeeee"], test: "teet", tututu: "tururuuu"]`. So that was it. Thanks, @Dogbert.

Comment: Also: `%{"t": "t"} == %{:"t" => "t"}` => `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For recursively converting `Maps` to `Keyword Lists` in Elixir:

```
defmodule MyMap do
  def to_keyword_list(map) do
    Enum.map(map, fn {k,v} ->
      v = cond do
        is_map(v) -> to_keyword_list(v)
        true      -> v
      end

      {String.to_atom("#{k}"), v}           
    end)
  end
end
```

But as @Dogbert already mentioned, ["Pure" Atoms cannot contain codepoints above 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351625/elixir-phoenix-binary-to-atom?noredirect=1&lq=1), so your map keys should be simple Strings / Atoms:

```
iex(1)> MyMap.to_keyword_list(%{"caligueva" => %{speeking: "speeeeeeee"}, "test" => "teet", "tututu" => "tururuuu"})
[caligueva: [speeking: "speeeeeeee"], test: "teet", tututu: "tururuuu"]
```

Comment: Does `String.to_atom("#{k}")` make it so any type that is placed in it becomes a string and then an atom?

Comment: Yep, as long ad it supports String to chars protocol

Answer (score 2):

Here is the refactored code for conversion:

```
def map_to_keyword_list(map), do: convert(map)

defp convert(map) when is_map(map), do: Enum.map(map, fn {k,v} ->{String.to_atom(k),convert(v)}  end) 
defp convert(v), do: v
```

Comment: What advantage does this have? Why is it defined twice?

Comment: You can use convert functions as private. Editing the answer, changing def to defp.

Comment: Moreover can you explain more what is defined twice. @Besto

Comment: `convert` is defined twice.  The first one is executed when called and the argument is a map, the second one is executed when called and the argument is anything else.  If it's a map, the map is mapped to `{k, v}` for each key and value in the map.  The `v` value is also converted, so the resulting conversion from calling `map_to_keyword_list` will return a nested keyword list value whenever `v` is a map.